# Reusing cells with hidden / scaled components

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I reuse collection view cell as a custom radio button. As a radio button selection I use two views:

- border view
- mark view

Mark view is hidden and scaled. It is basically simple selection.

In `RadioButtonCollectionViewCell` :

```
var checkMark: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    view.backgroundColor = .darkGreyFts
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override var isSelected: Bool {
    get {
        return super.isSelected
    } set {
        super.isSelected = newValue
        isSelected ? checkMark.scaleAnimate(1) :     checkMark.scaleAnimate(-1)
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.infoLabel.text = nil
    self.checkMark.isHidden = false
}
```

UIView extension :

```
  func scaleAnimate(_ state: Int) {
        switch state {
        case 1:
            self.isHidden = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
            })
        case -1:
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.isHidden = true
            })
        default:
            break
        }
    }

// MARK: - UICollectionView delegate.

extension DriverFormsViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RadioButtonCollectionViewCell {
            cell.isSelected = true
            collectionCellSelectedAtIndexPath = indexPath
        }

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RadioButtonCollectionViewCell {
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - UICollectionView data source.

extension DriverFormsViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return optionsDictionary.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! RadioButtonCollectionViewCell
        let key = optionsKeys[indexPath.row]

        cell.infoLabel.text = optionsDictionary[key]
        cell.checkMark.isHidden = true
        if let collectionCellIsSelectedAtIndexPath = collectionCellSelectedAtIndexPath {
            if collectionCellIsSelectedAtIndexPath == indexPath {
                cell.checkMark.scaleAnimate(1)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

How I would be able to reuse view which is hidden/not scaled/not ? Whenever I scroll down and back to the collection selected cell is not selected - mean, check mark is hidden and whenever I click on this cell it goes without animations. Any ideas what might be wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As always: You have to add the `hidden` and `scaled` state to the data source model then it is considered in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @vadian you can see I remember 'collectionCellIsSelectedAtIndexPath' and it is called. Is it a difference to store extra properties in the model ?

Comment: If the cell is supposed to work like a radio button you can also use that variable. But before you select a new cell you have to **unselect** the current one. And instead of using `prepareForReuse` I would add `else` clauses in `cellForItemAt`

Comment: Yeah, I am using deselection on cell while selecting new one. Could you give a short code with your second option ?

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure to deselect the current cell before selecting a new one

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let currentSelectedIndexPath = collectionCellSelectedAtIndexPath, 
       let currentCell = cellForItem(at: currentSelectedIndexPath) as? RadioButtonCollectionViewCell {
       currentCell.isSelected = false
    }
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RadioButtonCollectionViewCell {
        cell.isSelected = true
        collectionCellSelectedAtIndexPath = indexPath
    }
}
```

And instead of using `prepareForReuse` I would add an `else` clause in `cellForItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! RadioButtonCollectionViewCell
    let key = optionsKeys[indexPath.row]

    cell.infoLabel.text = optionsDictionary[key]
    cell.checkMark.isHidden = true
    if let collectionCellIsSelectedAtIndexPath = collectionCellSelectedAtIndexPath, 
       collectionCellIsSelectedAtIndexPath == indexPath {
          cell.checkMark.scaleAnimate(1)
    } else {
          cell.checkMark.scaleAnimate(-1)
    }
    return cell
}
```